# I want to make this kind of text field in flutter as shown in this given below image

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout, textfield, flutter-animation

I am doing a project in flutter and it this kind of text field where depth is given  is attractive anyone can help me to do it.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic

and use

```
Neumorphic(
  child:TextField()
)
```